# Is there a ConTeXt equivalent for biblatex crossref?

Tags: bibliographies, context

With `biblatex` I was using `crossref` to shorten my `.bib` files, as can be seen in this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@periodical{DebatMem2002,
    title = {Le Débat},
    number = {122},
    langid = {french},
    date = {2002}
}
@article{ChartiersurRicoeur2002,
    author = {Roger Chartier},
    title = {Le passé au présent},
    crossref = {DebatMem2002},
    pages = {4--11}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{ChartiersurRicoeur2002}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: biblatex output]

Which keys should I use to achieve the same under ConTeXt. I found `xcrossref` and `percentcrossref` keys in Hans Hagen and Alan Braslau manual "Bibliographies. The ConTeXt way" but could'nt figure out how to use them.
Here is my ConTeXt MWE as a starting point

```
\language [fr]
\startbuffer [bib]

@periodical{DebatMem2002,
    title = {Le Débat},
    number = {122},
    langid = {french},
    date = {2002}
}
@article{ChartiersurRicoeur2002,
    author = {Roger Chartier},
    title = {Le passé au présent},
    xcrossref = {DebatMem2002}, %does not work the way I would expect
    pages = {4--11}
}
\stopbuffer
\usebtxdataset[bib.buffer]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]
\definebtxrendering [example][apa]


\starttext
\nocite[ChartiersurRicoeur2002]
\placelistofpublications
\stoptext
```

Comment: I would suggest asking on the context mailing list.

Comment: @Aditya I was exactly thinking about it today…